# DataSet query with Parameters does not work in Report Builder

Tags: mysql, dataset, parameterized, reportbuilder

The following picture shows the query and its result with no variables:

[image]

The next one shows the same query with a variable and a different result:

[image]

This how the parameter was set just before the query execution:

[image]

I have also tried setting the parameter without *''* but it produces the same result.

Any clue about what's going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: The DBMS is MySql

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This weird issue is due to the fact that SSRS is connected to MySQL by ODBC connector; therefore, the query parameters should be defined as `?` and their names are `Parameter1`, `Parameter2`, etc... in order of appearance

Source: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1354185

Answer (score 0):

In Report Builder 3.0 you can user parameters in a dataset query using the following syntax: 
WHERE sql_column_name = (@Parameter_name_in_ReportBuilder)

Example: 
SELECT * from [dbName].[dbo].[TableName]
WHERE Account=(@Parameter1)

Before you can run the report, you need to configure a paramter named Parameter1 (in this example, change this to the name of your parameter) in Dataset Properties - Parameters. The value field should be set to one of the parameters