# SSS Report Builder 3.0 Query Parameter - Report Preview

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

This is a bit strange to me. I am using a SSRS Report Builder 3.0 for creating a report. I have two options: 1. Use a filter linked with report parameter OR 2. Use a query parameter linked with report parameter.

In the first case, the report preview works perfect. I am using a simple query for filter with parameter (@parameter_a) applied on ID column:

```
Select ID, Name from tbl_Table
```

But when I use a query parameter linked to the report parameter, the preview is blank. For the query parameter, I use the below query:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM tbl_Table WHERE ID = @parameter_a
```

I am clueless on this. I have also tried keeping a default value or removing it. Refresh/View Report doesn't work either.

PS: I am using MySql ODBC connection. Both options in report work fine when used in a c# application and rendered programatically. Tried re-installing current version, older version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [MySQLCommand documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand.htm), there is reference to an older parameter syntax (not sure what version of MySQL you are using in this scenario).

> Using the '@' symbol for paramters is now the preferred approach
>   although the old pattern of using '?' is still supported. Please be
>   aware though that using '@' can cause conflicts when user variables
>   are also used. To help with this situation please see the
>   documentation on the 'allow user variables' connection string option.
>   The 'old syntax' connection string option has now been deprecated.

Instead of using `@`, can you try with `?`:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM tbl_Table WHERE ID = ?
```

The order of the parameters used in the query will have to match the order of the SSRS report parameters.

Comment: SSRS doesn't recognize parameters with ? predecessor. It requires a parameter to start with @.

Comment: That's it... Sorted. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Daniel I am having similar problem with MySQL Stored proc in my dataset.  I am using Query type as text and then using `call testProc
(
 ?, ?,?, ?, ?,?
);`  But it does not return any row. I am mentioning parameters in correct order in Parameter section of dataset. When I change my proc to just return all rows (removing parameter filter from queries), I get result in my SSRS report as well. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Got it working. I am still not able to see the result in Query designer but at least it working when I actually execute the report. Below link solved my problem. Didn't realize I have to literally change the parameters names to Parameter1, Parameter2 and so on..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814477/dataset-query-with-parameters-does-not-work-in-report-builder